# How to make a custom keyboard shortcut in Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I was looking for a keyboard shortcut to see all Applications and found the answer and thought somebody new to Debian 9 Stretch might find it useful, too.

For reference, this is what I googled: [linux shortcut to get to applications screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/459483/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard shortcut to see all Applications already exists in Debian (9 Stretch):

## **`super`** + **`a`**